# Logback Trace and span via opentelemetry in vertx java

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j, vert.x

What is the best way to get a trace and span in OpenTelemetry in a Verticle? The official examples are unfortunately not very helpful. It is shown how to set it up but not how to get a handle of it for manual instrumentation.

```
SdkTracerProvider sdkTracerProvider = SdkTracerProvider.builder().build();
  OpenTelemetry openTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
     .setTracerProvider(sdkTracerProvider)
     .setPropagators(ContextPropagators.create(W3CTraceContextPropagator.getInstance()))
     .buildAndRegisterGlobal();

  VertxOptions vertxOptions = new VertxOptions();
  vertxOptions.setTracingOptions(new OpenTelemetryOptions(openTelemetry));

  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(vertxOptions);
```

**Here is my logback file**

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="com.company.service.model.CustomLogJsonLayout">
      <jsonFormatter
        class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
      </jsonFormatter>
      <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampFormat>
      <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <logger name="io.netty" level="warn"/>
  <logger name="io.vertx" level="info"/>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

**CustomLogJsonLayout**

```
public class CustomLogJsonLayout extends JsonLayout {

  public CustomLogJsonLayout() {
    this.setIncludeMDC(false);
  }

  @Override
  protected void addCustomDataToJsonMap(Map<String, Object> map, ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
    map.putAll(iLoggingEvent.getMDCPropertyMap());
    super.addCustomDataToJsonMap(map, iLoggingEvent);
  }
}
```

I need to get trace and span. but unbale to get the tag that needs in logback xml to get it.